# Cannot find books added from PC onto Kindle

Tags: kindle, kindle-paperwhite

I have added 2 books from my PC onto my Kindle, into the Documents folder.
I was able to read it.

It only showed when I tapped on the Home icon (the Pentagon symbol), but when I click on Library it can't be seen there.

Recently I added 2 books from Kindle Unlimited, and now I can't find those books which I added from my PC.

But when I connect it to my PC I still can locate those books inside the Documents folder.

Please Guide me.

Comment: may be issue with the filename given and listed by kindle. check the difference - what name do you get if you import the book to calibre check with that name. or embed correct metadata via calibre. the problem will be solved

Answer (score 2):

I am unclear if this is two separate questions, or the same question asked twice. The first question appears to be a question pertaining to locating 2 books transferred from a computer to a Kindle via USB, and the second appears to refer to 2 books from Kindle Unlimited that were also transferred from a computer to a Kindle via USB. As both Kindle and Kindle Paperwhite are tagged, I will address both as they are not the same.

Whether it is a book you own or a Kindle Unlimited book, transfers are the same. Just remember that you don't own the KU books and there is a cap on how many titles you can have at once. Hopefully, I can be of some help, though.

Paperwhite Instructions:

After downloading the books to your computer you can transfer the files via USB from your computer to the Kindle's Documents folder, then click on "My Library" at the top left of your screen and your files should appear in the "Downloaded" tab.

Kindle Fire Instructions:

After downloading the books to your computer you can transfer the files via USB from your computer to the Kindle's "Books" folder. Then, on your Kindle Fire, tap the Books content library from the top of your screen, choose the "Device" tab, and your Kindle content should show up.

Just remember that EPUB, Mobi and DRM-protected files are not supported file formats, and not all Kindle content can be transferred. If you do have unsupported files you want to place on your Kindle, you can easily convert those files to AZW or PDF for free using http://ebook.online-convert.com/convert-to-azw3. I use this exclusively for my business and there is nothing to install, no pop-ups or malware, and it's much quicker than Calibre, which you have to download.